# Open external URL (Equivalent of "loadUrl" for iOS)

Tags: cordova

I am new to the phonegap world and using phonegap 2.0. 
I'm looking for an equivalent of the android api call "loadUrl" but for an iOS phonegap application.

I'm looking specifically for an Objective C equivalent rather than a javascript redirect in index.html because I want to load my pages whithin the phonegap browser but I want to keep the ability to open some URLs in safari using **target="_blank"** and OpenAllWhiteListUrlInWebView

I found a lot of people in my case but never found a proper answer.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could make it work was to edit the Cordova lib code itself...

That's my first time with Objective-C so my code might not be perfect, but in case it could help someone I'm glad to share :

https://gist.github.com/3252986

I'll be glad anybody comes up with a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to open links in the safari browser. For the pages you want to load within the app, maybe you could try fetching them using some javascript...

Anyways, here goes: Modify the MainViewController.m file in the classes folder by uncommenting the shouldStartLoadWithRequest function and replacing the content with this:

NSURL *url = [request URL];

if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
  return NO;
}
else {
  return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
}

I found this solution [here](http://solutions.michaelbrooks.ca/2011/02/15/open-external-links-in-safariapp/) but the site seems to be offline right now.